# How to pass local variable using redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to pass local variable in the same way I pass it with `render` method.

```
render :show, locals { reservation: reservation }
```

So I look for something like, but it doesn't work.

```
redirect_to new_reservation_path, locals { some_var:  some_var }
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `redirect_to` you are actually sending a response back to the browser with a `302` (by default) telling it to request the new location. This makes it impossible to just pass a variable into the destination action, as you would with `render`.

What you can do instead, is you can pass query parameters to the browser's new location

```
redirect_to new_reservation_path(reservation, some_var: some_var)
```

but this limits you to things that can reasonably be sent in a query parameter. You can read more about [`redirect_to` here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to).

Comment: You should be sure it's not an object of some class.